# Raspberry Pi 3 - Google Colab blank page

Tags: raspberry-pi, google-colaboratory, chromium

I am trying to run Google Colab on my Raspberry Pi 3 (Raspberry Pi OS).

If I try to open the page, it remains blank with a hint that Colab might not work on my browser (Chromium).
[image: Colab Blank Page]

The link to the FAQ only states that Colab should work on most browsers, e.g. Firefox. So I inistalled Firefox, but it does not work.

I have previously run Colab on my Pi, so I am a bit confused why it is no longer supported. How do you run Colab on Pi?